# Which is the most lightweight image format for converting graphviz to images

Tags: graphviz, graph-visualization

I am writing graphviz files using a program and generating `png` figures using dot. Sometimes I end up with such a large file which does not even load in `eog` (eye of gnome). Since my graph is only black and white, I was wondering what option should I pass to `-T` when using `dot` to generate figure such that size is minimized and I can still zoom in and zoom out without loosing much.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem as well, the issue is usually that, even if the image compresses well (both PNG and GIF usually does a good job), the image fails to load because most image viewing programs uncompress the image in memory before displaying it.

I ended up using PostScript, since most PostScript viewers (Evince would be one) only renders what is visible on screen, not the whole image.

Answer (score 0):

Try `−Tgif` to generate GIF output.  Since your image has only two colors you won't be bothered by the limited color palate.

Comment: GIF may compress slightly better, but PNG usually also perform very well for these types of images.